# Querying Multiple Custom Taxonomy Terms

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy

I created a new taxonomy called 'country' and have two terms items inside it: 'USA' and 'Canada'. How do I go about querying this info? I have a filter page with two checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="usa" value="USA" /> USA
<input type="checkbox" name="canada" value="Canada" /> Canada
```

How do I make the query show multiple results in case I have both boxes checked? I tried an array, but it didn't work.

```
<?php query_posts( array('country' => array($_POST['usa'], $_POST['canada'])) ); ?>
```

Comment: There are good suggestions in the answers below but I am not sure you are going to get a solid solution unless you post more detail, and more code.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use the `tax_query` argument for query_posts/WP_Query.

```
query_posts( array(
  "tax_query" => array(
    array(
      "taxonomy" => "country",
      "field" => "slug",
      "terms" => array( "usa", "canada" )
    )
  )
) );
```

The `tax_query` argument is an array, so you can query multiple taxonomies.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll have to clarify your query, but these might also be helpful:

**the_terms** Displays the terms of a custom taxonomy: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms

**get_terms** Retrieve the terms in taxonomy or list of taxonomies:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

I just found this after days of searching for this solution which may also be what you’re after.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848608/iterate-through-custom-post-type-by-custom-taxonomy-type-ordering-wordpress-pos