# Get multiple term objects by ids

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I have an array of ids that correspond to terms. How do I get the full term objects for each id?

```
$ids = array(1,2,3);
```

Ideally, I would love to be able to do something similar to the way [taxonomy queries](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/22584/27667) with `WP_Query` work, but obviously with terms instead of posts.

Comment: Could you not loop through the array and use get_term?

Comment: I could, and I did do that as a crutch to get the script working. But if there is a single function that can handle all of this for me, it would make my code simpler and shorter and I would be relying on the WordPress API more appropriately... and I would learn something new.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wonder if you mean something like [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms#Examples) modified Codex example:

```
// Fetch:
$terms = get_terms( 'category', array(
    'include' => array( 1, 2, 3 ),
) );

// Output:
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) )
{
     $li = '';
     foreach ( $terms as $term )
     {
       $li .= sprintf( "<li>%s</li>", $term->name );    
     }
     printf( "<ul>%s</ul>", $li );
 }
```

where `$terms` contains an array of term objects, empty array or the `WP_Error()` object.

Check the Codex on [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) to get more information on the *output* and the *input* arguments. There you can get more code examples.

Comment: That looks exactly what I am looking for. I misunderstood what `include` was actually including.

Comment: @Jeff That's great -  `exclude` should work in a similar way and if `include` is empty then every term is included. Just remember to use the correct taxonomy (`category`, `post_tag`, ... ) else you will get the `WP_Error` object.

Answer (score 0):

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

Create a foreach loop for your array.

```
foreach($ids as $id) {
    $terms[$id] = get_term_by('id', $id, 'category');
}

var_export($terms);
```

You can then do what you want with the data.